# Adding c3p0 to spring hibernate project

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, timeout, c3p0

I had some trouble with connection timeouts. Problem: After mysql timeout hibernate stops working. It seams to work fine, but it does not write further data to database. After searching the logs, I found the hint: last connection 53000 seconds - connection problem. Timeout is mysql-default (28000). So I tried increasing mysql timeout, but won't use in production system.

Searching for a better solution, I found out, that probably c3p0 could solve my problem with a test query.

I am using hibernate with spring. That's were trouble starts. I added c3p0 as DataSource (Bean):

```
<bean id="dataSource_archiv" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${hibernate.connection.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${hibernate.connection.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${hibernate.connection.maxIdleTime}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${hibernate.connection.maxStmts}" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${hibernate.connection.testCo}" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="${hibernate.connection.testCo}" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${hibernate.connection.testSQL}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${hibernate.connection.testPeriod}" />
</bean>
```

[Complete hibernate Config File.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf6461fc6bc6b8592b39)

But afterwards, the application cannot be started anymore:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field
```

[Complete Stack trace.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/abc9f8d93d224e320f33)

So probably I misconfigured something. Where  can I start analyzing the problem?

Or is there any other good solution? Like starting a Native SQL from hibernate to keep connection alive? I would prefer the solution with c3p0.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) instead. Adding a different datasource is a as simple as adding a different provider and configuring appropriately. You also want to read the [Mysql Configuration Tips](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration). It also looks like you are missing proper transaction configuration and that you are messing around with sessions/transactions yourself instead of using spring declarative tx management.

Comment: Thanks for your hint (HikariCP), seems very interesting and lightwight. I like. But I could not find a way to configure a `testIntervall` like in c3p0.

Comment: Because it isn't there, check the MySQL info on how to do that. Also you shouldn't need to check only on checkout to refresh a connection.